# Rejected game variant for adding a new chess piece

Tags: chess-variants, minor-variations

Some time ago İ had a book on chess, that proposed new chess variant invented by some guy, in which a new chess piece was added. so instead the usual 8 by 8 board would get replaced by a bigger 9 by 9 board in which a new piece could be added. This piece would be like the queen but it would be able to jump like knight making it a lot more powerful than the queen.

So my question is, what did you call this new piece that was proposed and who made it at what year? Any info on the subject is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was unable to find a variant with a 9x9 board that included this piece, but that doesn't mean such a variant doesn't exist.

Perhaps you slightly misremembered the powers of the piece. [Modern Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Chess_(chess_variant)) was invented in 1968 by Gabriel Vicente Maura, according to Wikipedia.  It has a 9x9 board and features a piece called the "prime minister" which combines the powers of the bishop and knight.  Unlike any piece in normal chess, it is capable of delivering checkmate without the help of another piece, if the opponent's king is in the corner.

It's also possible you may be thinking of [Chancellor Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancellor_Chess).  This was  invented by Benjamin R. Foster in 1887, according to Wikipedia.  It has a 9x9 board and features a piece called the "chancellor", which combines the powers of a rook and knight.

If you're sure that the piece was actually a queen and knight combined (and not a bishop and knight or rook and knight), then Wikipedia says this is called the "[amazon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_(chess))", and that it has also been called "angel, ayanu, commander, crown prince, elephant, empress, general, giraffe, grand chancellor, maharajah, rettah, royal guard, superqueen, tetra queen, and wyvern".

Comment: hmm i am not sure exactly which one it is, but if i had to take a guess i would say that it was the first answer, the"prime minister" because the name rings more of a bell than the other ones. but none the less this is extremely useful information. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the privilege of meeting Gabriel Vicente Maura in Puerto Rico when i was a teenager in the 80s. He brought to life in the 70s the World Federation of Modern Chess (Femdam) with the new piece called the Prime Minister which moves like a Knight and a Bishop on a 9x9 Chessboard.[image: Eduardo A. Jusino- Modern Chess Set].

Comment: Two dark squared bishops? So basically white has no light square control of the board from move 1?

Comment: want a white Bishop then hop the black one like a knight and voila